# Command handler not working | Discord JS v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to build a command handler, but I can't run commands. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

```js
const args = message.content.slice(bot_info.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
let command = client.command.get(cmd);
if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
if (command) command.run(client, message, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `command` which is `undefined`, it means that the message is not starting by a command name. I can't guess what is the `result` so I think it is `command`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `let command = client.command.get(cmd);`
I forgot to type a s. It runs perfectly fine with `client.commands.get(cmd);`